# There is a space between divs that i don't understand why?

Tags: html, css

The lobby divs has space between eachother but when i removed container's center codes that fixing it.

Sorry for my bad english, i tried to convey my problem with using translate

> html codes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <div id="lobbies" class="active">
                    <p><i class="fa-solid fa-earth-americas"></i> Lobbies</p>
                </div>
                <div id="private-lobbies">
                    <p><i class="fa-solid fa-lock"></i>Private Lobbies</p>
                </div>
                <div id="gamemodes">
                    <p><i class="fa-solid fa-gamepad"></i> Gamemodes</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <main>
                <div id="lobbies-section">
                    <div class="info">
                        <h1 class="title">6 Active Lobbies</h1>
                        <p class="description">Select a session and join.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list">
                        <div class="details">
                            <div class="flex-1"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i></div>
                            <div class="flex-8">name</div>
                            <div class="flex-5">owner</div>
                            <div class="flex-4">players</div>
                            <div class="flex-1"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="active-lobbies">
                            <div class="lobbies">
                                <div class="lobby list-items">
                                    <div class="flex-1 random-color"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i></div>
                                    <div class="flex-8">Frosty's Fun Lobby</div>
                                    <div class="flex-5">frosty</div>
                                    <div class="flex-4">31</div>
                                    <div class="flex-1"><i class="fa-solid fa-right-to-bracket"></i></div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="lobby list-items">
                                    <div class="flex-1 random-color"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i></div>
                                    <div class="flex-8">Frosty's Fun Lobby</div>
                                    <div class="flex-5">frosty</div>
                                    <div class="flex-4">31</div>
                                    <div class="flex-1"><i class="fa-solid fa-right-to-bracket"></i></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="lobby list-items">
                                    <div class="flex-1 random-color"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i></div>
                                    <div class="flex-8">Frosty's Fun Lobby</div>
                                    <div class="flex-5">frosty</div>
                                    <div class="flex-4">31</div>
                                    <div class="flex-1"><i class="fa-solid fa-right-to-bracket"></i></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="lobby list-items">
                                    <div class="flex-1 random-color"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i></div>
                                    <div class="flex-8">Frosty's Fun Lobby</div>
                                    <div class="flex-5">frosty</div>
                                    <div class="flex-4">31</div>
                                    <div class="flex-1"><i class="fa-solid fa-right-to-bracket"></i></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="lobby list-items">
                                    <div class="flex-1 random-color"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i></div>
                                    <div class="flex-8">Frosty's Fun Lobby</div>
                                    <div class="flex-5">frosty</div>
                                    <div class="flex-4">31</div>
                                    <div class="flex-1"><i class="fa-solid fa-right-to-bracket"></i></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="lobby-info">
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>

        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

> css codes

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap");
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  user-select: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 4px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: rgba(4, 5, 7, 0.9);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgb(209, 95, 118);
}

html,
body {
  font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif !important;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
  width: 60vw;
  height: 60vh;
  position: relative;
  /*top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
}

.container .header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.container .header div {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: rgba(4, 5, 7, 0.9);
  margin-left: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.container .header div p {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
}
.container .header div p i {
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.container .header div:nth-child(1) {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.container .header .active {
  color: rgb(4, 5, 7);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(209, 95, 118);
}

main .info {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  background-color: rgba(4, 5, 7, 0.9);
  padding-left: 5px;
}
main .info .description {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
main .list {
  font-size: 14px;
}
main .list .details {
  overflow: auto;
  scrollbar-gutter: stable;
  padding: 13px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(4, 5, 7, 0.9);
  font-weight: bolder;
  display: flex;
}
main .list .active-lobbies {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 36.5vh;
}
main .list .active-lobbies .lobby {
  padding: 13px 10px;
  background-color: rgba(4, 5, 7, 0.9);
  display: flex;
}

.flex-1 {
  flex: 1;
}

.flex-2 {
  flex: 2;
}

.flex-3 {
  flex: 3;
}

.flex-4 {
  flex: 4;
}

.flex-5 {
  flex: 5;
}

.flex-6 {
  flex: 6;
}

.flex-7 {
  flex: 7;
}

.flex-8 {
  flex: 8;
}

.flex-9 {
  flex: 9;
}
```

Centering container by using display flex, justify-content and align-items resolving my problem by the way but i am trying to understand this.

Comment: [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAOEc.png) -
[Removing center code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5VK5.png) -
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biim5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Usually the technique that you used is for centering absolute positioned elements, as they don't respect the DOM flow. For centering non absolute positioned elements like yours is enough with this:

```
element {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

When you use `translate` to center an element in some moments you can get that issue that comes from rendering non entire pixels (like 12.5px) that are computed by CSS when you translate 50%. Lets suppose the element has a height of **271px** when you translate it 50% it's going to move **135,5px**.

Comment: Thank you for answer, i knew your shared codes fixes my problem but I can't position everything where I want with display flex method. Do u have a suggestion or should I be careful with even numbers when using "transform: translate"?